# jsf hibernate crud form relationship

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces, crud

i am using hibernate 4, jsf 2.2 and primefaces 4.
When i am creating an entity CRUD form with relationships which strategy should i use?

use object for relationship, and an entity generic converter :

```
<h:inputHidden id="gender" value="#{user.gender}" converter="entityconverter"/>
```

or use object.id

```
<h:inputHidden id="gender_id" value="#{user.gender.id}" />
```

**Update :**
i am using standart entities created by Netbeans with Entity from database.

User.java:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "gender", referencedColumnName = "id") 
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
private Gender gender; 

public Gender getGender() {
    return gender;
}
```

Gender.java:

```
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
@Basic(optional = false)    
@Column(name = "id") 
private Long id

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: To me object.id looks generic and simpler. Is entityconverter is specific to any particular framework like JSF ?

Comment: when i use object.id i get NullPointerException for object when loading form for first time. Entityconverter is a custom faces converter. Tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaus.html

Comment: Can you post the code for user.getGender() & gender.getId() ?

Comment: i am using standart entities created by Netbeans with Entity from database. Updated question with codes.

Comment: Also the user.getGender() & gender.getId() code ?

Comment: codes are added to question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first time when you load the page the gender property is null hence you get NPE.
Can you try by adding a null check like this,

```
public Gender getGender() {
    if(gender == null) {
        gender = new Gender();
    }
    return gender;
}
```

Comment: yes i know it. But my entities are generated by reverse engineering in netbeans. And i will have to edit all the entities if i use this strategy. And after a change in tables i will recreate entities and all changes will gone. Instead i would prefer to initialize it backing bean of the form. I want to learn if java gurus use this method or they use faces converter.